# Running javascript to close a div in googleads creative

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

This page https://www.perlentaucher.de/static/yl-raw.html has a div at the beginning that I want to close.

If I run

```
parent.document.getElementById('div-gpt-ad-1407836088099-0').style.display='none';
```

in the console of Google Chrome, the div will close. However if I put this code inside of a google ad manager third party creative. I always get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"

Comment: Maybe that statement runs too early before the div is created...?

Comment: I am not sure. I have 2 connected ad units there. If I put the code in the creative of the first, it works. If I put it at the 2 one (after passing through the first) it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
function addNewStyle(newStyle) {
    var styleElement = document.getElementById('styles_js');
    if (!styleElement) {
        styleElement = document.createElement('style');
        styleElement.type = 'text/css';
        styleElement.id = 'styles_js';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleElement);
    }
    styleElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newStyle));
}

addNewStyle('#div-gpt-ad-1407836088099-0 {display:none !important;}')
```

before
[image]

after
[image]

Comment: Doesn't show any error in the console but not working yet :-( Thanks a lot

Comment: it does work in the console, but not inside the line item creative :-/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that with each new ad unit's creative connected to that one was necessary to add parent. in the code. So at the end it looks like this:

```
parent.parent.parent.parent.document.getElementById('div-gpt-ad-1407836088099-0').style.display='none';
```